# Sequelize multiple databases on different servers

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, orm, sequelize.js

I am using Node, Express, Angular and Sequelize for database ORM. Everything is working great so far, but I just got a requirement to add an additional datasource to the sequelize/node backend.

How would I go about setting up two different databases (db1 on one server and db2 on a different one) in Sequelize and using them side by side?
Is this even supported, do I need to write up something of my own for it? I have looked around everywhere, but cannot find any mention of doing something like this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: When you say two different databases, do you mean completely different databases with separate schemas, or just two instances of the same schema (possibly replicated?)

Comment: I'm not sure how invested you are in Sequelize, but the [**sails.js**](http://sailsjs.org) ORM supports cross-datasource joins, even if they are different types (e.g. you can join MongoDB against PostgreSQL) or whatever.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the schemas are different (for example, db1 is your User/Groups database and db2 is your Orders database), you can just create two Sequelize instances:

```
var db1sequelize = new Sequelize('db1', 'db1user', 'db1pass'...);

db1sequelize.define('User', {...})
db1sequelize.define('Group', {...})

var db2sequelize = new Sequelize('db2', 'db2user', 'db2pass'...);

db2sequelize.define('Order', {...})

User.findAll(...)  // queries db1
Order.findAll(...) // queries db2
```

I suspect, however, that associations between those wouldn't work well. For example, you could definitely associate Users and Groups because they would all fall in the same schema:

```
User.hasMany(Group);
```

but to associate between Orders and Users I would instead just add the column manually.

```
db2sequelize.define('Order', {
  userId: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  ...
})

User.create({...}).then(function(createdUser) {      // inserts in db1
  return Order.create({userId: createdUser.id, ...}) // inserts in db2
});
```

I'm also not sure how transactions would work between those databases...

Comment: Thanks man, the way you did it works. I actually ended up creating two different folders of models for two different databases because i wanted to keep keep collecting all models and associating them if need be without having to worry about importing each new model every time i need to use it. Associations do not work, but for the project i'm working on they don't really need to so it's all good. Thanks again

Comment: How to do this, if you have the same models in each of the databases?